# How to force scheduler to run on specific core in kernel mode

Tags: windows, assembly, kernel, driver, scheduler

I'm trying to read the MSRs on multiple cores with a kernel mode driver. RDMSR can't read certain MSRs (APERF) from other cores. How do I force the scheduler to run a thread on a specific core. Is there any way to find where the scheduler stores thread and process information?

Right now my solution is to set the affinity using KeSetSystemAffinityThreadEx then check the core with CPUID and finally retry if it's wrong. I need a more reliable way to switch cores.

Comment: Terminology: Scheduling is a distributed algorithm.  Each core runs the scheduler function to figure out what it should run next.  It presumably uses interlocked operations to make sure the same task can't start on 2 threads at once.  But anyway, there isn't a "master control program" that assigns threads to cores.

Comment: Instead of making your task bounce around to multiple cores, would it be useful to broadcast an IPI (inter-processor interrupt) to run an interrupt handler on every core?  Or send targeted ones to specific cores?  IDK what kind of tradeoff between intrusive vs. low-latency you want.  Otherwise probably Windows has a scheduler function you can call from any point in a kernel task where it's safe to do so.  At least that's how Linux works; you just call `schedule()` or `yield()` to invoke the scheduler on the current core. (Which should refuse to let your task keep running when core != affinity)

Comment: Also on linux you have a kernel function to read MSR from other cores already implemented. Maybe similar exists for windows.

Comment: I think there are only two approaches: 1) You call your driver from different usermode threads pinned to different CPUs. As long as no filter drivers have been attached on top of your driver, it'll be called in the context (i.e. cpu) of the calling thread. 2) You use a DPC and set it's target with [`KeSetTargetProcessorDpc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-kesettargetprocessordpc). This requires handling a request asynchronously, the WDF should help handling the flow correctly.